# How to perform a task in a specified time in unity 3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In **Cocos2D** I have used so many actions such as CCMove, CCRotate, CCEaseIn, CCScale etc.

As you can observe all these actions have a parameter such as specified time interval. For example if I use CCMoveTo with position (100, 100) from (0, 0) and time as 5 secs then it moves a node in 5 secs.

Suppose I change the position to (10, 10) then also it moves in 5 secs. I mean the task is completed in definite time interval, irrespective of distance moving, amount of rotation, scale or whatever the task is.

Now coming to unity, I just want to have all these utilities for Unity too. I want to write utility classes for all these. I am a bit confused of using Time.deltatime in this scenario.

Please provide your suggestions in general for performing any task in definite time interval. Please provide any code samples if you have.

Comment: search for some tween package. There are many.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there aren't any built-in functions like you desire.

I've been using a class I created quite a lot in my own Unity game, to assist me with the timing of changing one value to another. I've called it **`SmoothStepHelper`**, and I'll post the code here; maybe it will help you out!

```js
class SmoothStepHelper {
    var startTime:float;
    var endTime:float;
    var duration:float;

    function GetPercentage () : float {
        return (Time.time - startTime) / duration;
    }

    static function CreateWithDuration (newDuration:float) : SmoothStepHelper {
        var helper:SmoothStepHelper = new SmoothStepHelper();
        helper.duration = newDuration;
        helper.startTime = Time.time;
        helper.endTime = helper.startTime + helper.duration;
        return helper;
    }

    function IsDone () : boolean {
        return Time.time >= endTime;
    }
}
```

So, if you want to change a value from A to B smoothly, try something like this:

```js
var positionA:Vector3 = Vector3(0,0,0);
var positionB:Vector3 = Vector3(0,0,100);
var duration:float = 5;
var ssh:SmoothStepHelper;

function Start () {
    ssh = SmoothStepHelper.CreateWithDuration(duration);
}

function Update () {
    var smoothStep:float = Mathf.SmoothStep(0f, 1f, ssh.GetPercentage());
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(positionA, positionB, smoothStep);
    if (ssh.IsDone()) {
        // The 5 seconds has completed, do something else here
    }
}
```

---

*My original answer, wherein I misunderstood the question:*

I find using the [`Invoke`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) method works well.

So for example, say you wanted to change an object's position 5 seconds after the object starts:

```js
var foo:float = 10;

function Start () {
    Invoke('MoveOver', 5);
}

function MoveOver () {
    transform.position.x += foo;
}
```

Comment: I think you have not understood my question. I want to move an object to attain a position (0, 0, 100) from (0, 0, 0) in 5 secs continuously or smoothly. Not immediately after 5 secs. When I want to move it should move continuously for 5 secs and it should have positioned in the target position.

Comment: Take a look at Vector2.MoveTowards, which seems to do what you want. But you need to calculate the "steps" yourself, and you need to read up on Time.deltaTime.

Comment: @KumarC I have edited my answer with something more useful hopefully!

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions. But this solution also doesn't work. While testing my target position was (0, 0, 10). If I change the time to 15 instead of 5 secs it is my target object is positioned in just 8-10 secs. I want to make an object move in exactly 15 secs. I mean till 15 secs it should still be changing its position.

Comment: @KumarC Can you edit your question and add some code?